# Have chrome.tabs.reload() reload a tab other than the active tab

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

As my first extension, I am trying to use `chrome.webRequest` API to reload webpages which, when it is not available, the web server redirects the request to another URL. My extension will keep on trying the original request (`tabs.reload`) if redirect is found (`onBeforeRedirect` event occurs).

Everything works fine, except that I can not make it run on multiple tabs. The extension can create one tab and keep on reloading, but when I click the extension icon to open another tab or when I click on other inactive tabs, *background.js* stops running.

How can I modify it to run on multiple tabs (for example, 5 tabs concurrently) without stopping?

Here is **background.js**:

```
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(activeTab) {
   var newURL = "https://myurl";
   chrome.tabs.create({ url: newURL });
});

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect.addListener(function (details) {
    console.log("Redirect -> Reload");
    chrome.tabs.reload();
}, {
    urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}, ["responseHeaders"]);

chrome.webRequest.onResponseStarted.addListener(function (details) {
    console.log("Response Started");
    console.log(details.url); 
    console.log(details.statusLine);
    if (details.url === "https://myurl" && details.statusCode === 200 ) {
        console.log("Finally");
    }
}, {
    urls: ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"]
}, ["responseHeaders"]);
```

**manifest.json**:

```json
 {
  "name": "My Tool",
  "description": "My Tool",
  "version": "1",
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"]
},
  "permissions":[
    "https://myurl",
    "http://redirectedurl",
    "webRequest",
    "webRequestBlocking",
    "tabs"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Why are you wanting your extension to reload tabs when the URL is redirected? It is *very* rare for the response from a server to change from a redirect to serving the page.

Comment: I can see some possible reasons why you might want an extension to reload *specific* tabs, or URLs, which are redirected (e.g. you want to camp on a specific URL until the response is available). However, in that case, you would only want it enabled on a per tab, or per URL, basis, not all tabs. Having it run on all tabs indiscriminately could disrupt normal web surfing. You may also want to implement some delay between reloads to limit how hard you are pounding on a particular URL and the resources you are taking up on the local machine.

Comment: Yes, this is the exact reason why I want my extension to reload tabs. I might not describe my question well enough. My question failed to include _specific_ tab, _particulart_ URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have not tested your code, one reason it will not work on anything other than the active tab of the current window is that you do not pass an argument to [`chrome.tabs.reload()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-reload). Without an argument, it defauls to reloading the active tab in the current window regardless of which tab actually triggered the [`chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRedirect`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#event-onBeforeRedirect) event. To have the tab which actually triggered the `webRequest.onBeforeRedirect` event be reloaded, you will need to pass an argument with the tab ID to `chrome.tabs.reload()`, something like:

```
chrome.tabs.reload(details.tabId);
```

Comment: I have seen this code many times during my search for a solution but did not realize that it is the case. It works like a charm when I add this to my extension. Thanks.